# How to find broken links in Selenium + Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find a broken link in Selenium and Python but getting an error in the code:

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_driver_path = "D:\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe"

driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path)

driver.get('https://google.co.in/')
links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a")
images = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("img")
for link in links:
    r = requests.head(link.get_attribute('href')
    print(r.status_code == 200)
```

Unable to find broken links on the page is there is some other solution?

Getting:

> raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
>   urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='myaccount.google.com', port=443): Max
>   retries exceeded with url: /?utm_source=OGB&utm_medium=app (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol
>   (_ssl.c:777)'),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation
>   of protocol (_ssl.c:777)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: can you maybe add the error you get and please put the code sample into text instead of using screenshots

Answer (score 3):

To find the status of the links on the page you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import requests
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://google.co.in/')
  links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a")
  for link in links:
      r = requests.head(link.get_attribute('href'))
      print(link.get_attribute('href'), r.status_code)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm 302
  https://www.google.co.in/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi 200
  https://www.google.co.in/intl/en/options/ 301
  https://myaccount.google.com/?utm_source=OGB&utm_medium=app 302
  https://www.google.co.in/webhp?tab=ww 200
  https://maps.google.co.in/maps?hl=en&tab=wl 302
  https://www.youtube.com/?gl=IN 200
  https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8 302
  https://news.google.co.in/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn 301
  https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm 302
  https://www.google.com/contacts/?hl=en&tab=wC 302
  https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo 302
  https://www.google.com/calendar?tab=wc 302
  https://plus.google.com/?gpsrc=ogpy0&tab=wX 302
  https://translate.google.co.in/?hl=en&tab=wT 200
  https://photos.google.com/?tab=wq&pageId=none 302
  https://www.google.co.in/intl/en/options/ 301
  https://docs.google.com/document/?usp=docs_alc 302
  https://books.google.co.in/bkshp?hl=en&tab=wp 200
  https://www.blogger.com/?tab=wj 405
  https://hangouts.google.com/ 302
  https://keep.google.com/ 302
  https://earth.google.com/web/ 200
  https://www.google.co.in/intl/en/options/ 301
  https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=https://www.google.co.in/ 200
  https://www.google.co.in/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0qNPqnqHbAhXYdn0KHXpeAo0QPAgD 200
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Because of You are missing closing bracket on the below line or is it typo?

```
r = requests.head(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_driver_path = "D:\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path)
import requests
for link in links:
    r = requests.head(link)
    if r.status_code!=404:
         driver.get(link)
    else:
          print(str(link) + " isn't available.")
```

Comment: looks like incomplete code to me, from where we will get the value of links and link. Please correct